# Abstract Method In Abstract Class In java

Tags: java, abstract-class

Is it possible in Java? Or can I use any method before define it?

I tried it in Abstract class but JVM said abstarct method can't be static. Then I tried define class to object but i did not use 'extends'. Both of them gave me a error.

Comment: Yes, you can call an abstract method from within an abstract class since you are guaranteed that whichever instance you have at runtime has implemented that method. Show some code of what you are trying to do, what your class and methods look like. `static` however is a completely different topic.

Comment: Can you give me an little  example about it?Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's possible to call an abstract method before defining it in the abstract class. Assume you have designed a base formula class:

```
public abstract class AbstractFormula {

    protected abstract void initialize();

    public double evaluate() {
        initialize();
        //
        // do the logic
        //
        return 0d; // the result
    }
}
```

Also assume the logic for evaluating formula is to:

1. initialize the coefficients
2. do the math to calculate the result

So the default implementation of the `evaluate()` method is to call the `initialize()` method and then do the calculation. In other word, you may not know the logic of initializing coefficient in all possible implementations of `AbstractFormula`, but you can call it in other methods of the abstract class.

**But** you can **NOT** create a static abstract method in the first place. Because static methods are class methods and can be called without creating a object of that class. So having an static abstract method is pointless. `static` methods should have their body when they are being defined.

Comment: Thanks for answer.

Comment: Glad that helped! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you also can use abstract method, but not static. Static method must have a body even if they are part of abstract class because one doesn't need to create instance of a class to access its static method.

Comment: I understand but i dont know how can i do it right way.Can you give me an little example with abstract class?

Comment: You can read more there: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html

Comment: Or show me some of your code and I will try to solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

You **can** invoke an abstract method on an Object as for the Object to exist it itself must have instantiated a class that extended the abstract class (thus implemented the method).

You **cannot** create a static abstract method as when you attempt to invoke the method there would be no implementation for it. Static methods are invoked on the Class.

```
public abstract class AbstractClass {
    public static abstract void staticAbstract();
    public abstract void instanceAbstract();
}
```

Take the above example; I've defined two methods there.

To invoke the static method, you would invoke it on the AbstractClass, `AbstractClass.staticAbstract();`, however, AbstractClass has no implementation for this method. How would your compiler know what to do with the method?

However, to invoke the instance method, you would need to invoke it on an Object. As you cannot instantiate an abstract class, for the Object to exist such that you may invoke the instance method, the class that the Object belongs to must have implemented the method.

```
public class RealClass extends AbstractClass {
    public instanceAbstract();
}
```

The Class `RealClass` extends the `AbstractClass`, hence it **must** implement the `instanceAbstract();`.

```
AbstractClass class = new RealClass();
class.instanceAbstract();
```

You create an instance of `RealClass`, for the purpose of demonstration you assign it to a variable of type `AbstractClass`. You can invoke the abstract method on the Object despite the `AbstractClass.instanceAbstract();` method having no implementation; `RealClass` provides the implementation.